# Should maxLength restriction for string datatype in XSD be based on pre- or post-encoded data?

Tags: encoding, xsd, maxlength

If the longest value for a string in my DB is

```
"ABC<DEF"
```

should the maxLength restriction for this string datatype in the XSD be 7 (pre-encoding) or should it be 10 (post-encoding), i.e.

```
"ABC&lt;DEF"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: pre-encoding.

Encoding characters in XML doesn't affect the "real" length value of the string.

Quick test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="2"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Valid XML :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">&amp;1</root>
```